# ToolStripContainer Tool Property

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a windows forms application in c# and I use ToolStripContainer Tool to load another form to my main windows form. It is seen like that :
[image]

But I don't want to see child page top frame. How can I hide it? I use this code to show child page in the main page:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        childPage d = new childPage();
        //toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(d);
        d.TopLevel = false;
        d.ControlBox = false;
        d.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(d);
        d.Show();
    }
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        childPage d = new childPage();
        d.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(d);
        d.Show();
    }
```